# Limits for expected value in a proof

Tags: probability, inequality

I have a small step in a proof, that I'm not sure if I got it right.

> > We have given the function $f(s):=\mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda S (s-1)}]$ where $S$ is a random variable such that:
> >     $$0<\mathbb{E}[S]< \infty \text{ and } \lambda \mathbb{E}[S] >1.$$
> >     Then it follows that: $$0<f(0)<1.$$

So this is my proof, I hope anybody can say if that is right or not:

$f(0)=\mathbb{E}[e^{- \lambda S}]= \mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{e^{\lambda S}}]$.

i) By conditons, we have: $\lambda \mathbb{E}[S] >1 \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{\lambda \mathbb{E}[S] } <1$

$$\Rightarrow f(0)=\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{e^{\lambda S}}] <1.$$

ii) On the other hand: $\lambda \mathbb{E}[S] >1$ and $0<\mathbb{E}[S]$.
$$\Rightarrow \lambda < \infty.$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{\lambda \mathbb{E}[S] } >0.$$
$$\Rightarrow f(0)=\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{e^{\lambda S}}] >0.$$

I hope anybody can help me! I appreciate any idea or help! Thank you very much!

Comment: Might be easier to note: $\lambda \mathbb{E}[S] > 1 \iff 0 < \frac{1}{\mathbb{E}[\lambda S]} < 1$.  Together with $\mathbb{E}\left[\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda S}\right] = \mathrm{e}^{-\mathbb{E}[\lambda S]}$.

Comment: @EricTowers Why should the last equality hold?

Comment: @saz:  Jensen's Inequality and $\exp(- \cdot)$ is a convex function.  ... which indicates a typo':  $\mathbb{E}\left[ \mathrm{e}^{-\lambda S} \right] \leq \mathrm{e}^{-\mathbb{E}[\lambda S]}$.

Comment: @EricTowers Jensen's inequality is the other way round: $$e^{-\mathbb{E}(\lambda S)} \leq \mathbb{E}e^{-\lambda S}.$$ And this means that this does inequality cannot be used to prove $f(0)<1$.

Comment: @saz:  You are exactly right.  I don't know what's wrong with me tonight.  Meh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim does not hold true. Consider for example a Gaussian random variable $S$ with mean $1$ and variance $1$. Then

$$\mathbb{E}e^{-\lambda S} =  \exp \left(-\lambda+\frac{1}{2} \lambda^2 \right).$$

Obviously, we have

$$f(0)=\mathbb{E}e^{-\lambda S} >1$$

for $\lambda \mathbb{E}S = \lambda >1$ sufficiently large.